# How to print the TAX or GST of products seperately with tax rates

Tags: magento2.1.6

I need to print the tax rates of different products separately.Currently i could get the total tax when i'm placing order.I had already changed Tax Calculation Method Based On unit prize in configuration.Please help me to fix it.

[image]

Configuration settings
[image]
[image]
[image]